# How to fix "underflow"?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I am using `Truffle v5.5.5`  and `solidity 0.8.0`.

I have the following constructor in my contract:

```
contract rNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost; // = 0.0 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 999999999999999999;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 1;
  bool public paused = false;
  bool public revealed = true;
  string public notRevealedUri;

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI,
    string memory _initNotRevealedUri,
    uint256 _cost
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
    setCost(_cost);
  }
```

So basically the costs can also be set for the contract.

When deploying with truffle I use the following:

```
var rNFT = artifacts.require("../contracts/rNFT.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(rNFT, "rNFT", "rNFT", "www._initBaseURI.com", "www._initNotRevealedUri.com", 0.12);

};
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"rNFT" -- underflow (fault="underflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=0.12, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8).

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:379:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:68:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:54:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:202:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:152:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:117:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:94:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:78:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:44:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1)
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> Error: underflow (fault="underflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=0.12, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:348:1
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:68:1)
      at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:54:1)
      at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:202:1)
      at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:152:1)
      at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:117:1)
      at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:94:1)
      at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:78:1)
      at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:44:1)
      at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:189:1) {
    reason: 'underflow',
    code: 'NUMERIC_FAULT',
    fault: 'underflow',
    operation: 'BigNumber.from',
    value: 0.12,
    hijackedStack: 'Error: underflow (fault="underflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=0.12, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)\n' +
      '    at lib_esm_Logger.makeError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:166:1)\n' +
      '    at lib_esm_Logger.throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:175:1)\n' +
      '    at throwFault (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib.esm/bignumber.js:273:18)\n' +
      '    at Function.from (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib.esm/bignumber.js:175:1)\n' +
      '    at NumberCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/number.js:13:17)\n' +
      '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:57:1\n' +
      '    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at pack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/array.js:43:1)\n' +
      '    at TupleCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/coders/tuple.js:19:16)\n' +
      '    at AbiCoder.encode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib.esm/abi-coder.js:82:1)\n' +
      '    at ABICoder.encodeParameters (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:120:1)\n' +
      '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:438:1\n' +
      '    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at Object._encodeMethodABI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:437:6)\n' +
      '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:275:1\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)'
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? I just want to set the costs for each NFT in the contract.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Solidity doesn't support decimal numbers. Use full integers

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I tried using `  deployer.deploy(rNFT, "rNFT", "rNFT", "www._initBaseURI.com", "www._initNotRevealedUri.com", 120000000000000000);
` however I get the following error again `"rNFT" -- overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=120000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8).
`

Answer (score 1):

```
deployer.deploy(
    rNFT,
    "rNFT",
    "rNFT",
    "www._initBaseURI.com",
    "www._initNotRevealedUri.com",
    **0.12**
);
```

you can’t have **`0.12`**, there is no float on EVM

If by **0.12** you meant **0.12 ETH**, it should be instead `120000000000000000` (18decimals).

There is a nice `wei` to `ether` [converter here](https://eth-converter.com/extended-converter.html)

Comment: Just a precision, the error is actually coming from Ethers.js, it's not an arithmetic underflow per say (it never reached the EVM), just Ethers.js implementation that forbids non integer BigNumber values as can be seen here  (https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/4e6d121fb8aa7327290afab7653364be8ddd8d81/packages/bignumber/lib.esm/bignumber.js#L196) , `ethers.BigNumber.from(2.0)` is perfectly valid for example.

Comment: If I use the wei format I still get the error: `"rNFT" -- overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=120000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8).
`

Comment: it should be a string or BN